# Font looks different in wordpress that in google fonts

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, google-fonts

I'm having a problem and already search but i cant find an answer. I'm using a google font (Playfair Display) in my Wordpress site (Html5Blank Theme) but it looks very different that in google fonts.  this is how they look in [googlefont](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imoVN.png) and [my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swQr8.png).

---

This is my code

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,700,900|Roboto:100,300');

h3 {
  display: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: ‘Playfair Display’, serif;
  font-size: 10vw;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  color: #F4512C;
}
```

```html
<h3>2017</h3>
```

Comment: How is the style when you inspect in the console ?

Comment: I think you are not using the right quotes here : **"‘Playfair Display’" should be  "Playfair Display"**

Comment: this is what appears in console h3 {
    display: inherit;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: "‘Playfair Display’", serif;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: rgb(244, 81, 44);
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0px;
}

Comment: thanks @br.julien that was the problem! btw im new in here so how can i check your anwser?

Comment: Change  font-family: ‘Playfair Display’, serif; to font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were problem in your quote style - Use `'Playfair Display'` instead of `‘Playfair Display’`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,700,900|Roboto:100,300');

h3 {
  display: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  font-size: 10vw;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  color: #F4512C;
}
```

```html
<h3>2017</h3>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have used wrong quotes. I think you have just copied and paste the line from some text file.

Use `font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;` instead of `font-family: ‘Playfair Display’, serif;`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,700,900|Roboto:100,300');
h3 {
  display: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  color: #F4512C;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-class">
  <h3>2017</h3>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a problem with this. Neris font works but Playfair doesnt (not is wordpress btw. just code)

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
      fontFamily: {
        playfair: "'Playfair Display', serif",
        neris: "'Neris', sans",
      }
   }
}
```

```css
@layer base {
  @font-face {
    font-family: "playfair";
    font-weight: 700;
    src:
      url("../public/font/playfairdisplay-bold-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
      url("../public/font/playfairdisplay-bold-webfont.woff2") format("woff2");
  }
}
```

```html
<h2 class="text-wbm-grey font-playfair text-6xl font-bold">
  Playfair Display
</h2>
```